# Create complex file name from user input

Tags: python, filenames, user-input

I’m trying to adapt a script that currently contains the following segment:

```
#  Initialize the output files
working_dir = os.getcwd()
output_path = "{}/{}".format(working_dir, "output_Prelim")
if not os.path.exists(output_path):
    os.mkdir(output_path)
data_file = "{0}/RWA_2010_BUFFER_by_1.csv".format(output_path)
error_file = "{0}/failed_queries.txt".format(output_path)
```

In the statement that begins “data_file,” the parts of the file name “RWA” and “2010” refer to the country and year in which a particular survey was conducted.

I’m trying to adapt that segment so that the file name preserves the same general format, but allows the user to enter a different country code and year.

I can generate a string called “file_name” that looks right, using the following code:

```
print('Enter the country code')
cCode =input()
print('The country code is '+cCode)
print('Enter the survey year')
srvyYear =input()
print('The survey year is '+srvyYear)

file_name = r'"{0}/'+cCode+'_'+srvyYear+'_'+'BUFFER300_by_1.csv"'\
```

When I print “file_name,” I get

```
"{0}/BDI_2009_BUFFER300_by_1.csv"
```

That looks right, but am not sure what to do with it - in particular, how to get it understood as a file name rather than as a string.  When I try to concatenate that string with the remainder of the statement that begins “data_file,” I get a syntax error.

Obviously I need to do a tutorial, but am not sure what to look for.

Many thanks, and apologies for the newbie question.

Comment: Can you show the error and the line it happens at?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is exactly, but if you want to replace the `{0}` part with something else (e.g. the value in `data_file`), you can just do `file_name.format(data_file)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `join()` method for string and `os.path.join()` for paht? e.g.

```
file_name = os.path.join(out_path, '_'.join([cCode, srvyYear, 'BUFFER300_by_1.csv']))
```

You can see its doc [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), I believe that is what you needed, you'd better not concatenate string by yourself to construct path or filename. By the way, `os.path.join()` can construct filename without platform dependence, it will be a smart choice (especially for Windows).